# Two basic questions on the -l(blah) flag while compiling / installing programs

Tags: linker

I am new to Ubuntu and I had the following questions.

1. When compiling a C or any other program one often writes a command such as **gcc hello.c -lm**
   I am told the **-lm** option is for explicitly linking the math library during the compiling
   phase. I wanted to know where the library 'foo' is supposed to be located if linked with -  lfoo.
2. This is an error I get when I was trying to install a package named SUPERLU which in turn depends on the existence of a package named PARMETIS. (ending of the stuff after running *make*)

   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find **-lparmetis**
   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
   make[1]: *** [pddrive] Error 1
   make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/gaurish108/Desktop/ResearchMeetings/SUPERPETS/SuperLU_DIST_2.4/EXAMPLE'
   make: *** [example] Error 2

What should I  do ???? I found that there is no ld folder in my /usr/bin/......Should I modify my make.inc file in some way?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_21.html. `-lm` says "search for libm.a in the search path". libm.a is found in /usr/lib/libm.a.